# Customize lines based on specific criteria with plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I'm coding in R and I have the following dataframe and plot:

```
df1 <- data.frame(term = c(1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 2, 4),  
                 vol=c(10, 11, 12, 12.3, 9, 9.5, 11, 15, 13, 20), 
                 date=c("2019","2019","2019","2019","2018","2018","2018","2018", "2019swp","2019swp"), stringsAsFactors = F)
plot_ly(data = df1, x=~term, y=~vol) %>% add_trace(type='scatter',mode='lines', color=~date) %>%
  layout(title=paste0("Impled Vol Term Structure"),
         xaxis=list(title='Term (years)'),
         yaxis=list(title='Implied Vol (%)'))
```

however, what I'm trying to achieve is a way to tell my plot: "if the line is the one labeled "2019swp" then the line has to be a dashed line, otherwise a normal line is ok".
I've been reading the plotly online tutorial but I can't find a way to achieve this specific goal. I can see how to customize markers and colors but not the line style.
Any suggestions? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another column to your dataframe which contains the line style

```
df1 = within(df1, {
     style = ifelse(date == '2019swp', 'solid', 'dotted')
})
```

and then use this line style in your `plot_ly` call

```
plot_ly(data = df1, x=~term, y=~vol, linetype=~style)
```

See [here](https://plot.ly/r/line-charts/#style-line-plots) for some more examples.

[image]

**Complete code**

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
df1 <- data.frame(term = c(1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 2, 4),  
                  vol=c(10, 11, 12, 12.3, 9, 9.5, 11, 15, 13, 20), 
                  date=c("2019","2019","2019","2019","2018","2018","2018","2018", "2019swp","2019swp"), stringsAsFactors = F)

df1 = within(df1, {
     style = ifelse(date == '2019swp', 'solid', 'dotted')
})

plot_ly(data = df1, x=~term, y=~vol, linetype=~style) %>% 
  add_trace(type='scatter', mode='lines', color=~date) %>%
  layout(title=paste0("Impled Vol Term Structure"),
         xaxis=list(title='Term (years)'),
         yaxis=list(title='Implied Vol (%)'))
```

Comment: Fantastic, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!